# app.factory not retrieving JSON

Tags: angularjs, json

First my files:

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("CODETEST", ['ngRoute']);

// Routing Configuration
app.config(function($routeProvider) { 
$routeProvider
    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'HomeController', 
        templateUrl: 'index.php'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

});
```

people.js

```
app.factory('users', ['$http', function($http) { 
function callExternalJson() {
    return $http.get('js/services/testperson.json')
}

return callExternalJson;
}]);
```

HomeController.js

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'users', function($scope, $rootScope, users ) {

users.success(function(data){
    $scope.users = data.person;
});

}]);
```

Here's the problem.

This is just a test JSON file to get this working, but the actual JSON file I'll be retrieving from dynamically regenerates on each hit, which is why I have `people.js` set up that way because I was hitting an infinite loop. Someone last night helped me with that.

However, I still have two problems:
1) How do I extract the data in my controller so that I can use it in the page?

2) The get in `people.js` is returning an empty struct. I'm sure the file is there, but it's not getting any data.

Thoughts?

Comment: I tried that. When I changed it to users.callExternalJson() it said it didn't exist.

Comment: I apologize, I misread the definition; you do indeed have it correct here; the name the function threw me for a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Change your factory code to the following,

```
app.factory('users', ['$http', function($http) { 
    return {
        // you can add multiple functions separating them with comma and access them in your controller
        callExternalJson: function() {
            return $http.get('js/services/testperson.json').then(function (response) {
                return response;
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

And in your controller,

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'users', function ($scope, $rootScope, users ) {
    users.callExternalJson()
      .then(function (response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: On the one hand, I don't seem to be in some infinite loop, but the data still isn't showing up and it's throwing an unexpected token error on the open brace after `then(response)`

Comment: @ReverendDovie I made a syntax error. Didn't close the brackets correctly. I've updated my code. Can you check once?

Comment: I had tried that as well, this now takes me back to the infinite loop. :(

Comment: Do you have any other code along with this? I don't understand why it is going into infinite loop.

Comment: Neither do I. Here's the page. I put it in a live spot: http://www.gelerinter.com/dev_sites/ps/#/

Comment: ARGH! So I had it working on the local version, but now it won't let me make a cross-origin get request!

Comment: Where is your `.json` file now? Inside your project folder?

Comment: Yes. I am using a test JSON file in the project folder, but the one I really need to use is a link they sent me but Angular won't let me make the cross-origin request.

Comment: So that is the issue of their server. They need to configure to allow CORS.

Comment: I tried this, but it also didn't work on my site, despite working on his example page: http://benalman.com/code/projects/php-simple-proxy/docs/files/ba-simple-proxy-php.html

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `index.php` from `templateUrl`.

`templateUrl` should contain specific HTML for your route, not the entire HTML page. Now, the `ng-view` is getting populated with the whole page which goes haywire.

If I look at the source of your page, you don't need a templateUrl at all for your app to work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
users().then(function(response){
    $scope.users = response.data.person;
});
```

Comment: Ok, partial success. On the display page, it displayed one of the many pieces of information in the JSON but not the rest, and it's still stuck in some sort of infinite background loop that eventually crashes the page.

Comment: Can you post the data info in response.data and HTML?

Comment: No, now it's in the infinite loop again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how to do this but I want to mark two of you as the correct answer. The overall code from @Chinni was the answer for that, and the templateUrl thing from @Prashant-palikhe solved the loop.

Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Probably this might help in this case :) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262210/whats-the-right-way-to-self-answer-if-other-answers-assisted